# Why does a static library have a class with an init method?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, shared-libraries

When I create a new shared iOS library `CoreServices` then there is a class created `CoreServices` which has an `init` method.

Does that mean that every library will somehow be instantiated through this object? If not what is this object good for?

Comment: Try setting a symbolic breakpoint there and see if it hits.

Comment: Do you mean you created a project called `CoreServices` with Xcode's iOS library template?

Comment: @mattjgalloway That's correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it isn't, that's just a template class that's created with the library. I will usually delete the implementation file for this and use the header as the public header for the library (i.e. import all the externally visible classes in this header file).